# Esperando uma página carregar

Tags: c#, listview, desempenho, uwp

Tenho uma página inicial, e ao clicar em um botão, navego para a próxima página.
O problema é que essa página faz uma consulta no banco e retorna muitos registros, que são inseridos em 3 `listviews` diferentes. Aí o app fica travado até terminar essa pesquisa e preencher os `listviews`.
Como mostrar um `progressring` enquanto a página carrega e só exibir a ela após ela estar completamente disponível?

Comment: Está trabalhando com Web ou Winforms?

Comment: @AlexandreCavaloti, coloquei na tag, uwp